# PHP - If number is divisible by 3 and 5 then echo

Tags: php, math

I'm new to PHP and trying to create the following whilst minimizing the amount of code needed. PHP should show a list of 100 then display if the number is / by 3, 5 or 3 and 5. If not by any then show nothing.

This is what I've got so far, but any help would be great since not sure about the / by 3 and 5 bit as you can see below.

```
<?php $var = range(0, 100); ?>
  <table>
<?php foreach ($var as &$number) {
 echo " <tr>
    <td>$number</td>
    <td>";

    if($number % 3 == 0)  {
    echo "BY3";
} elseif ($number % 5 == 0) {
    echo "BY5";
} elseif ($number % 3 and 5 == 0) {
        echo "BY3 AND 5";
}
 echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>

  </table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Reminds me of [ProjectEuler problem 1](https://projecteuler.net/problem=1)

Comment: This reminds me of FizzBuzz problem, ProjectEuler #1 is a behemoth compared to this question.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Nope... you should check first if it's divisble for 15 (3x5) (or 3 and 5) and after you can do other checks:

```
if($number % 15 == 0)  {
    echo "BY3 AND 5";
} elseif ($number % 5 == 0) {
    echo "BY5";
} elseif ($number % 3 == 0) {
    echo "BY3";
}
 echo "</td></tr>";

?>
```

Because every number divisble for 15 is also divisble for 3 and 5. So your last check could never hit

Answer (score 5):

if I'm reading your question correct then you are looking for :

```
if ($number % 3 == 0 && $number %5 == 0) {
        echo "BY3 AND 5";
} elseif ($number % 3 == 0)  {
    echo "BY3";
} elseif ($number % 5 == 0) {
    echo "BY5";
}
```

Alternative version :

```
echo ($number % 3 ? ($number % 5 ? "BY3 and 5" : "BY 3") : ($number % 5 ? "BY 5" : ""));
```

Comment: You'll never hit the third conditional...for it to be true, one of the first two must be as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$num_count = 100;
    $div_3 = "Divisible by 3";
    $div_5 = "Divisible by 5";
    $div_both = "Divisible by 3 and 5";
    $not_div = "Not Divisible by 3 or 5";

    for($i=0;$i<=$num_count;$i++)
    {
        switch($i)
        {
            case ($i%15==0):
            echo $i." (".$div_both.")</br>";
            break;
            case ($i%3==0):
            echo $i." (".$div_3.")</br>";
            break;
            case ($i%5==0):
            echo $i." (".$div_5.")</br>";
            break;
            default:
            echo $i."</br>";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please avoid posting code-only answers.  Old code-only answers encourage new code-only answers.

Answer (score 2):

No need to do three if statements:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {

    echo "<tr><td>{$i}</td><td>";

    if ($i % 3 == 0) echo "BY3 ";
    if ($i % 5 == 0) echo "BY5";

    echo "</td></tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

This is neater and completed to be run:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) { 
                if ($i % 15 == 0)
                {
                    echo"Divisible by 3 and 5</br>";
                }
                elseif ($i%3==0)
                {
                    echo"Divisible by 3</br>";
                }
                elseif ($i%5==0)
                {
                    echo"Divisible by 5</br>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo $i,"</br>";
                }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the code as given below

```
<?php $var = range(0, 100); ?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($var as &$number)
{
echo " <tr>
<td>$number</td>
<td>";

if($number % 3 == 0 &&  $number % 5 == 0) 
{
   echo "BY3 AND 5";
} 
elseif ($number % 5 == 0) 
{
echo "BY5";
}
elseif ($number % 3 == 0) 
{
    echo "BY3";
}
echo "</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if($number % 5 == 0 && $number % 3 == 0)  {
    echo "BY3 AND 5";
} elseif ($number % 5 == 0) {
    echo "BY5";
} elseif ($number % 3 == 0) {
    echo "BY3";
} else{
    echo "NOT BY3 OR 5";
}   
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($number % 15 == 0)  
{
     echo "Divisible by 3 and 5";
} 
elseif ($number % 5 == 0) 
{
    echo "Divisible by 5";
} 
elseif ($number % 3 == 0) 
{
 echo "Divisible by 3";
}
```